# Image upload with axios react native android

Tags: android, react-native, image-upload, react-native-image-picker

I am trying to upload image to an API the iOS version is working good but there is problem in android, My code is bellow.

```
const uploadUri =
    Platform.OS === 'ios'
      ? uploadImageFile.replace('file:', '')
      : uploadImageFile;
  // console.log(uploadUri);
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('file', {
    uri: uploadUri,
    name: 'file',
    type: 'image/jpg',
  });
  Axios.post(`${API.BASE_URL}/user/image`, data, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: token,
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      setActivity(false);
      setIsImageEdit(false);
      console.log('success');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      setActivity(false);
      if (error.response) {
        console.log(error.response.data);
        console.log(error.response.status);
        console.log(error.response.headers);
      } else if (error.request) {
        console.log(error.request);
      } else {
        console.log('Error', error.message);
      }
      setIsImageEdit(false);
    });
```

The error response I get is

```
{"DONE": 4, "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2, "LOADING": 3, "OPENED": 1, "UNSENT": 0, "_aborted": false, "_cachedResponse": undefined, "_hasError": true, "_headers": {"accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*", "authorization": "7aeb23f62bd748c39c9e8652eb1056e2"}, "_incrementalEvents": false, "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": {}, "_method": "POST", "_perfKey": "network_XMLHttpRequest_https://capi-test.beebl.io/user/image", "_requestId": null, "_response": "Could not retrieve file for uri /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/images/image-448777a5-1734-41f4-857e-a99d5239c279.jpg", "_responseType": "", "_sent": true, "_subscriptions": [], "_timedOut": false, "_trackingName": "unknown", "_url": "https://capi-test.beebl.io/user/image", "readyState": 4, "responseHeaders": undefined, "status": 0, "timeout": 0, "upload": {}, "withCredentials": true}
```

"_response": "Could not retrieve file for uri /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/images/image-448777a5-1734-41f4-857e-a99d5239c279.jpg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

in AndroidManifest.xml